Numeric Edit Control for ATL/WTL
Here's a demo of Numeric Edit Control for MFC. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6296/Numeric-Edit-Control-2
But I'm working on this WTL / ATL control.
template <class TBase>
class CEditT : public TBase
{};
typedef CEditT<ATL::CWindow>   CEdit;

You can find the definition in here https://codedocs.xyz/AnotherFoxGuy/crashrpt/classWTL_1_1CEditT.html
It doesn't have PreTranslateMessage like in MFC. Then, how do I trigger WM_KEYDOWN at first?

IIRC Bjarke Viksoe had some useful examples, bit aged, but still relevant. e.g. https://www.viksoe.dk/code/editfilter.htm

A good WTL/ATL application typicaly have a PreTranslateMessage.
See the TabBrowser sample from WTL, it is a perfect example.

@DanMašek, Great! This code's really helpful!
